# Is it possible to host Asp.net MVC web App locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, localhost

I want to host Asp.net MVC Web Application locally on IIS, my actual aim is to search the link my locally host application while laptop not connected to internet and my website launches. I have tried many way but neither work for me. Upto now I only achieved the result which shows the content on the webpage, which are the default contents and folder of any Asp.net MVC application e.g Controller, App Start, Models, Scripts and not launching my home page. When i search my link this image is showing. [Content shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBgWz.png) But I want to come the page which i given in the app start/route config file

Comment: You have to open a remote desk top to run applications.  All you have is access to the file system and no machine to run applications.  You do not have access on the IIS to run any application.  When you double click on an app you are trying to run on IIS and not the remote machine.

Comment: Can you share the details of what you have tried? Is it .net framework application or .net core application?

Comment: It is .net application and i tried and only acheived this solution. the image i shared

Comment: When i change any code in the web.config file this image not shows then. I don't know what relation these both have

Comment: Try doing a publish from Visual Studio. Right-click the project and publish.

Comment: Disable directory browsing on IIS, and set a default page to display for `/` as the old thread indicated.

Comment: How can i set default page, It is mvc in which web.config file or global.asax we don't set default page. default page is set in route.config file in app start folder